# UIWebView scrollBy replacement

Tags: javascript, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

For an iPhone app I was using window.scrollBy to scroll to the bottom of a page.  The page is rendered in a UIWebView.  This all worked fine untill sdk 3.0.  It is documented that scrollBy is not supported in UIWebView anymore.  Is there an handy javascript replacement for window.scrollBy?

Comment: Try using window.scrollTo(x,y);

Also i want to know where is it mentioned that "scrollBy is not supported in UIWebView anymore". Please send some URL may be i would get some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following methods to solve your problem.

**For getting the pageOffset:**

int pageYOffset = [[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];

**For getting the total scroll height of a webpage:**

int scrollHeight = [[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] intValue];

**For scrolling the webpage to a particular offset:**

[webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollTop = %d",scrollHeight ]];